# cannot run **npm start** after installing cra with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

I'm trying to get started with react & typescript . After creating an empty folder in vscode then I create a TypeScript app with `npx create-react-app react-script-demo  --template typescript`  the installating completed . but after  running `npm start` . I got theese errors  :

> 'typescript\react-script-demo\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:***************\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

I checked other question in stackoverflow but none of them worked for me

Comment: Is there `node_modules` directory in your project dir?

Comment: Yeah, the structure as it should be

Comment: Can you try to remove `node_modules` and run `npm i`

Comment: Hi ! i tried it but didn't work for me , actually the problem has no thing to do with react and the installation . but the name of the parent  folder contains **&** in the name it was like this `react&typescript` after renaming it with no **&** like this `reactAndTypescript` it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error has nothing to do with the installation. I figured out that the error is coming from the name of the parent folder containing an **&** `(Ampersand)` . renaming this folder with no & symbol  solved the problem